# ArrayList with enums

Tags: java

I need help to be able to return a list of attributes from an enum.

It currently generats an error.

The enum:

```
public enum EnumServices {

    GYM,
    SWIMMING_POOL,
    SECURITY,
    SUM,
    STORAGE,
    GARAGE
}
```

The code I'm writing in another class:

```
@Override
public List<EnumPropertyType> findAllPropertiesTypes() {
    return List <Property> EnumPropertyType = new ArrayList();
    propertiesTypeList.add("GYM");
    propertiesTypeList.add("SWIMMING_POOL");
    propertiesTypeList.add("SECURITY");
    propertiesTypeList.add("SUM");
    propertiesTypeList.add("STORAGE");
    propertiesTypeList.add("GARAGE");
}
```

What's wrong there?

Comment: What do you think `return List <Property> EnumPropertyType = new ArrayList();` is doing? And what do you think the statements after that do?

Comment: I think it would be returning a list of the attributes that I have inside the enum. Or actually that's what I need and maybe I'm doing it wrong and it's done in another way ...

Comment: Are you trying to make a list of strings, or a list of the values of your enum? Because your method declares return type `List<EnumPropertyType>` but inside the method you seem to be adding strings to a non-existent list.

Comment: Of enum, but i got it without this.
"enumPropertyType.add"

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of inconsistency.

1. You define a type called EnumServices (which is nowhere used).
2. You have a method returning a list of EnumPropertyType (which is nowhere defined).
3. You're trying to return a list of Property, which has no visible relationship to either of the above two types.
4. You're putting String values into something called propertiesTypeList, which is not defined.
5. You expect to execute code after a 'return' statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish here, but I think you can try one of these two approaches

```
    EnumServices[] array = EnumServices.values();
    List<EnumServices> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I already ansuer my oun question whit this list code...

```
@Override
public List<EnumPropertyType> findAllPropertiesTypes() {
    List <EnumPropertyType> enumPropertyType = new ArrayList();
    enumPropertyType.add(EnumPropertyType.HOUSE);
    enumPropertyType.add(EnumPropertyType.APARTMENT);
    enumPropertyType.add(EnumPropertyType.PH);
    return enumPropertyType;
}
```

thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your line:

```
return List <Property> EnumPropertyType = new ArrayList();
```

…ends that method. Your new empty `ArrayList` object is returned to the calling method. Below that line, your calls to `propertiesTypeList.add(` never execute.

## `EnumSet`

Your Question is confused, but I am guessing that you want to collect some of your enum objects. Java has a class for that: `EnumSet`.

The [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html) class is an implmentation of [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html). A `Set` disallows duplicates. The `EnumSet` class is highly optimized for holding enum objects, taking very little memory and executing very quickly.

And, while a `Set` promises no particular ordering, an `EnumSet` object holds its elements in the order in which they were defined on the enum. So for example, the [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum is defined in MONDAY, TUESDAY, … , SUNDAY order, an `EnumSet< DayOfWeek >` will iterate its elements in that order.

Here is an example using your enum, renamed here to `Service`. (Tip: An enum should be named in the singular.)

```java
public enum Service {
    GYM,
    SWIMMING_POOL,
    SECURITY,
    SUM,
    STORAGE,
    GARAGE
}
```

Collect a few of those.

```java
Set< Service > spaces = EnumSet.of( Service.GYM , Service.SWIMMING_POOL , Service.STORAGE , Service.GARAGE ) ;
Set< Service > nonSpaces = EnumSet.of( Service.SECURITY , Service.SUM ) ;
```

## `List.of`

If you want to collect some of your enum objects in an arbitrary order, then use a `List`. In modern Java, you can use `List.of` to instantiate an unmodifiable list using brief literals syntax.

```
List< Service > someServices = List.of( Service.SECURITY ,  Service.GARAGE , Service.GYM ) ;
```